# How to run Facebooks Examples on React Native? ["AwesomeProject" not found]

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native

Actually it seems not to be able to run facebooks examples in the ReactNative-Repository. Just an example with the MovieApp:

Steps to reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/react-native.git
cd react-native && npm install
open Examples/Movies/Movies.xcodeproj
```

In XCode hit **Run**.

The iOS Simulator will start and prompts an error screen:

> Cannot find entry Examples/Movies/MoviesApp.ios.js in any of the roots
>   ["./AwesomeProject"].

The special thing here is the fact that at "root" is only a "AwesomeProject" given.

In the movie example there is no "AwesomeProject"-string available at the whole code base (except in .md-Files)
Why is "AwesomeProject" requested?

Running a grep:

```
grep -HR "AwesomeProject" *
```

lists only .md-Files naming this string.

[image]

```
$ node -v
v5.2.0
```

OS: OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: I did every step, as you described and everything works as expected. Could you check if you can open the url `http://localhost:8081/Examples/Movies/MoviesApp.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is a previous session of the package manager already running a project named "AwesomeProject". Have you tried out the getting started tutorial before, which would still being active in package manager?

Just close alle Terminals to ensure that there is no package manager running, close your xcode just to be on the safe side and start again with the steps you already reported.